# Issues with finding element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to copy data from the following website:  https://imljail.shelbycountytn.gov/IML.

The site has two buttons, both labelled "Search."  The button I want to press has the following code:

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr align="right" style="color: #000000;"> 
<td><a href = "javascript:setNameSearch()" onkeydown="keyDownNameSearch()"><img src = "../images/button_up_search.gif" alt = "Search Button" /></a> <a href = "javascript:resetNameSearch()" onkeydown="keyDownNameReset()"><img src = "../images/button_up_reset.gif" alt = "Reset Button" /></a></td></tr></table>
```

I don't need to fill in any of the fields - all the data I want appears when you leave the name fields blank and just click the button.

I've been using Selenium and have been able to locate/load the page, but can't get it to find the right element and click it.  Any ideas of how to specify this button?  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('URL...)
driver_find_element(By. [tried ID, LINK_TEXT, PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, etc.]
```

Comment: The site is not responding

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on your url. From which country do you access the page?

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr align="right" style="color: #000000;"> 
        <td>
            <a href = "javascript:setNameSearch()" onkeydown="keyDownNameSearch()">
                <img src = "../images/button_up_search.gif" alt = "Search Button" />
            </a> 
            <a href = "javascript:resetNameSearch()" onkeydown="keyDownNameReset()">
                <img src = "../images/button_up_reset.gif" alt = "Reset Button" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To click on the *`<a>`* element with attribute *`alt = "Search Button"`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='setNameSearch'] > img[alt='Search Button']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'setNameSearch')]/img[@alt='Search Button']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```